# PHP 7.1 connect to AD with TLS(ldap_start_tls)

Tags: php, ssl, openssl, ldap

Trying to connect to LDAP using ldap_start_tls.

Getting an exception:

> PHP Warning:  ldap_start_tls(): Unable to start TLS: Can't contact LDAP server in /root/test/testldap.php on line 16

I turned on the debug: ldap_set_option(NULL, LDAP_OPT_DEBUG_LEVEL, 7);

But in a debug there are no errors, also there are no messages from TLS

Comment: You're going to have to include some code or more details.

Comment: Might be a network error, not your code.

Comment: i've been having trouble with this too..  the closest i've come to making this work is specifying LDAPCONF as an environment variable and running it through the CLI.  for some reason, the env var doesn't make it down to the LDAP library when run through Apache HTTPD.  I've had similar issues with the SSH libraries not being able to use an SSH Agent, too.